# Resharper Search with pattern method call

Tags: c#, replace, resharper

I want to replace this part of code using "Search with pattern...":

```
public bool IsDbObjectsOK()
{
    var result = 0;
    result = usp_IsDbObjectsOK();
    if (result == 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}

public bool UnlockWindow()
{
    var result = 0;
    result = usp_UnlockWindow();
    if (result == 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Replace with:

```
public bool IsDbObjectsOK()
{
    return usp_IsDbObjectsOK() == 0;
}

public bool UnlockWindow()
{
    return usp_UnlockWindow() == 0;
}
```

I tried to use

```
var $result$ = 0;
$result$ = $usp_IsDbObjectsOK$();
if ($result$ == 0)
    return true;
return false;
```

This doesn't work, because the method call isn't found in any of the code that needs to be replaced.

How to do this?

Comment: What you posted works for me using Resharper 7.1.3000.2254.  I set `result` as an identifier and `usp_IsDbObjectOK` as an expression when setting up the search.  What version of Resharper are you using, and what do you mean by "the method call isn't found in any of the code that needs to be replaced?"

Comment: Result as an identifier and usp_IsDbObjectOK as an expression did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear.  I've created an answer with this information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure that you use the correct [placeholder type](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Navigation_and_Search__Structural_Search_and_Replace.html#d92948e7609) when you set up the search.

Here, `result` should be an *Identifier Placeholder* and `usp_IsDbObjectsOK` should be an *Expression Placeholder*.  When I do that, the replace works as you'd expect.